# Application icon is correct in taskbar, but not in the start menu?

Tags: wpf, icons, clickonce

The application icon is shown correctly on the taskbar:

[image]

But on the start menu it is not:

[image]

The icon has been defined in [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) like this:

```
<Window Icon="icon.png">
```

And application is published using ClickOnce from Build, Publish menu in Visual Studio.

What is missing to properly show the application in the start menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to setup the Icon for the *Application*, not just the Window.  The Window icon is used for the Taskbar at runtime, and can be customized per window within your application.  The Application icon is used by default for the application as a whole, and gets used for shortcuts in the start menu.

The application icon is set in the Application Properties, under the "Application" section.

Under `Resources`, you can set the *Icon and manifest* to use your Icon for the Application itself, which is what will get used for the start menu.  The default selection is `(Default Icon)`, which provides you the icon you're seeing.